# File name compatible hash values in Java

Tags: java, hash, filenames

To generate some uniqueness in file system names of user-provided files, I generate a hash value of some other user-supplied data (in this case the user's IP address and a random integer) and prefix the filename with it. I chose the SHA-1 algorithm to perform this hash. Unfortunately, the String returned from

```
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
// Add values to the digest
String ipAddrHash = new String(md.digest());
```

...of course contains all sorts of weird exotic characters, most of which are not allowed in file names.

So, either:

- How do I transform the hash value string in a string that contains 'regular characters'  that I can use in file names?
- Is there a simple one-way function in Java for me to use that generates a irreversible value for me to use in a file name right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [encode the bytes in hexadecimal](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHexString%28byte%5B%5D%29) to get a printable file name. But your algorithm doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Or you could simply use a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), or a sequence number returned from a database sequence.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution to me. Changing the code to    

String ipAddrHash = new String(Hex.encodeHex(md.digest()));

using the Apache Commons library yields a filename compatible name.

Comment: @DCKing: why `new String()`? Strings are immutable. Use the result from the encodeHex method directly. But beware about potential collisions.

Comment: That's right, the new string is unnecessary. Uniqueness isn't necessary for me (a timestamp is appended to the file as well), I even cut off the hash string later.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String filename=UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only uniqueness use a `java.util.UUID`. FWIW, I had a similar requirement and this is what I used to solve it (software operating on both linux and windows). A UUID contains alphanumerics and hyphens only so no issues with incompatible file system characters and guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode returned String with Base32 or Base64 with replacing "/" character with safe one (for example: "_").